# Exportar imagens Blogger para Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, google, blogger

Estou migrando meu blog do Blogger para Wordpress. Como faço com as imagens, pois irei exportá-las e depois modificar uma a uma. Eu devo fazer redirecionamento 301? Isso é possível? Como proceder nessa situação?

Vejam bem, as URLs eu tenho que fazer redirecionamento 301. As imagens devemos proceder da mesma forma, para não sermos punidos pelo google?
*Apesar de achar que o blogger não seja possível este redirecionamento, com imagens.

Comment: Qual a dificuldade que está tendo?

Comment: Meu problema é na importação das imagens... pois elas estão em vindo com tamanho menor. Minha dúvida seria se irei perder visitantes de imagens pois irei trocá-las para minha url?... ATT

Comment: @abc, anota aí: quando alguém pedir esclarecimento ou quando você tem mais informação pra fornecer, **por favor**, edita sua pergunta.

Answer (score 2):

Você pode fazer a migração de diversas maneiras:

1) Migrando o conteúdo manualmente, recriando as publicações e salvando as imagens uma por uma. Nesse método você iria evitar bugs e falhas de formação, tendo em vista que ambos são diferentes. É o mais trabalhoso, mas também é o mais garantido.

2) Linkando imagens via URL. Ou seja, você recria apenas o conteúdo e as imagens você linka ela através da plataforma do Wordpress.

3) Exportando todas as publicações pelo sistema do próprio Blogger. As imagens iriam juntos também, porém podem ocorrer alguns bugs principalmente no quesito alinhamento. Caso queira seguir este método:

http://wiki.locaweb.com.br/pt-br/Transferindo_Blogspot_para_Wordpress

Comment: Eu encontrei, um plugin interessante, envia as imagens e tudo mais...  Mas o problema é que as imagens estão em tamanho menor... Ou seja, ele importa o tamanho de <img> e não do <a>... Daí irei tentar fazer um substituição para /s1600/ nas imagens.
Outra coisa que estou desenvolvendo é uma aplicação para remover essas TAgs do blogger, que cagam com as postagens...  ATT

Comment: Já tive esse mesmo problema quando tive que migrar um cliente para o Wordpress. Decidi eu mesmo fazer essa migração, para evitar dores de cabeça...

Comment: Eu fiz a migração das imagens acredito que foi com este plugin: SEO Blogger to Wordpress using 301 Redirection ...  Deu certo, mais algumas não parecem... acredito que pouco a pouco faço manualmente... deixando padronizado o site... ATT